# Can I drill a cast iron enameled shower pan for door installation?

Tags: shower, drill, cast-iron

Drill in hand, about to do it! Should there be concern here?

Comment: too late, already dood it

Comment: Tape around the spot you are drilling and keep the enamel cool with water or it will chip and pop. If it pops it is harder to cover but chipping is no problem in my experience a sharp carbide or titanium nitride bit helps make it through the enamel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can drill and tap the hole for threads. You may have figured that out already.